# In a 2d numpy array, how to select every first and second element of the inner arrays? Can this be done with indexing?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For example the array:

```
array = np.array([[1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 8],
                  [1, 1, 8, 2, 1, 16],
                  [1, 1, 40, 2, 1, 80],
                  [1, 2, 40, 2, 1, 80]])
```

I'd like to essentially remove every third `[:, ::2]` element of the inner arrays. So the result should be:

```
[[1 1 2 1]
 [1 1 2 1]
 [1 1 2 1]
 [1 2 2 1]]
```

I could do two selections and concatenate each of the resulting arrays, but that seem super slow.. is there a way to use indexing or some other method that doesn't involve a loop with np.concatenate?

My actual array always have inner arrays with sizes divisible by 3, and the 1 dimension is very, very large. So I'm interested in the fastest way to accomplish this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `boolean` indexing:

```
array[:, np.arange(array.shape[1]) % 3 != 2]

array([[1, 1, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 2, 1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [`delete`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) with a slice:

```
out = np.delete(array, np.s_[2::3], axis=1)
# or
# out = np.delete(array, slice(2, None, 3), axis=1)
```

Generic case:

```
n = 3
out = np.delete(array, np.s_[n-1::n], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 1, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 2, 1]])
```

Comment: Thank you! Both this answer and the one I accepted worked great - I went with the one that came in first but this one is solid as well.

Comment: `delete` can use different methods depending on the selector, but in this case I think it uses a boolean mask as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

While selecting every third column makes a `view`, `arr[:,::3]`, and thus is fast, deleting those has to make a copy in one way or other.  Keeping 2, skip 1, keep 2, etc is not a sufficiently regular pattern to implement with `basic` indexing.

Looking at times of the answers with your (4,6) sample:

```
In [41]: timeit np.delete(arr, np.s_[2::3], axis=1)
42.7 µs ± 216 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Under the covers `delete` is complex, taking different strategies depending on the delete pattern.

```
In [42]: timeit arr[:, np.r_[:2, 3:5]]
50.9 µs ± 242 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Explicitly selecting the columns to keep, is suprisingly slower.  I don't knonw how much of the problem is with the `np.r_` concatenate.  And as written this is not generalizable.  It only works for this 6 column case.

A boolean mask  is quite a bit faster:

```
In [43]: timeit arr[:,np.arange(arr.shape[1])% 3!=2]
22.8 µs ± 2.18 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Another way of generating the mask is:

```
In [44]: timeit mask = np.ones(arr.shape[1],bool); mask[2::3]=0; arr[:,mask]
20.5 µs ± 41.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

A much faster way is to reshape the array into  a 3d, with 3 columns, and taking the first two columns - with a final reshape:

```
In [45]: timeit arr.reshape(4,-1,3)[:,:,:2].reshape(4,-1)
3.93 µs ± 45.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [46]: arr.reshape(4,-1,3)[:,:,:2].reshape(4,-1)
Out[46]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 2, 1]])
```

The first 2 steps make a view; but the last reshape has to make a copy.

```
In [47]: arr.reshape(4,-1,3)[:,:,:2].base
Out[47]: 
array([[ 1,  1,  4,  2,  1,  8],
       [ 1,  1,  8,  2,  1, 16],
       [ 1,  1, 40,  2,  1, 80],
       [ 1,  2, 40,  2,  1, 80]])
```

As usual timings like this need to be taken with caution, recognizing alternatives may scale differently.

### big array timings

```
In [50]: arr = np.ones((4,10000*3))

In [51]: timeit arr.reshape(4,-1,3)[:,:,:2].reshape(4,-1)
523 µs ± 1.52 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [52]: timeit arr[:,np.arange(arr.shape[1])% 3!=2]
944 µs ± 2.85 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [53]: timeit np.delete(arr, np.s_[2::3], axis=1)
1.66 ms ± 20.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

The reshape approach is still faster, but without quite as big a gain.  I'm surprised that `delete` is still slower than the mask.

A faster way of using `delete` is to use `arange` directly:

```
In [57]: timeit np.delete(arr, np.arange(0,arr.shape[1],3), axis=1)
878 µs ± 21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Apparently `delete` takes a differnt approach when given a `slice` instead of an explicit array of delete columns.  The `arange` timing is closer to the boolean mask timing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use indexing to select every first and second element of the inner arrays in a 2D NumPy array. In NumPy, you can use the syntax array[:, :2] to achieve this. This syntax means that for every row (first dimension, represented by :), you select the first and second elements (second dimension, represented by :2). The :2 in the second dimension specifies that you start from the first element (index 0) and go up to but not including the third element (index 2), effectively selecting the first and second elements.

Here's how you can do it:

```
import numpy as np

# Example 2D NumPy array
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

# Select every first and second element of the inner arrays
selected_elements = arr[:, :2]

print(selected_elements)
```

This will output:

```
[[1 2]
 [4 5]
 [7 8]]
```

You are asking for different things in the title and summary areas. I answered the question in the title earlier. To answer the part in the detailed area:

Input:

```
array = np.array([[1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 8],
                  [1, 1, 8, 2, 1, 16],
                  [1, 1, 40, 2, 1, 80],
                  [1, 2, 40, 2, 1, 80]])

selected_elements = array[:, np.r_[:2, 3:5]]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 2, 1],
 [1, 1, 2, 1],
 [1, 1, 2, 1],
 [1, 2, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: The result does not match what OP wants

Comment: There asking for something different in the details, versus the title. So I answered what they requested in the title.