# Removing certain element indexes in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How do I go about removing all but a few certain element indexes of each row of a numpy array? For example, below, deleting the second and fourth elements of each row of the numpy array?

> before = [[1,4,5,6,1], [1,4,5,1,3], [1,4,5,1,0], [1,6,2,6,9],
> [8,4,4,6,7]]
>
> after = [[1,5,1], [1,5,3], [1,5,0], [1,2,9], [8,4,7]]

I have managed to do it by flipping the array using np.rot90(np.fliplr()) and then appending the elements of each row to a new array, then flipping it around again, but this is a bit long as my array is very large.

Comment: A recent similar SO, https://stackoverflow.com/q/78208703/901925.  Whether it's a duplicate depends on how either of you generalize the task.

Comment: Note that `np.rot90(np.fliplr(M))` is not really that expansive, and, more importantly, since you said "as my array is very large", doesn't depend on the size of the array. It is just a view (you can test it `np.rot90(np.fliplr(M))[0,0]=-1` does alter `M[0,0]`). So, it is a bit convoluted way of writing `M.T` (which is about 100 times faster. But both are very fast and take O(1) time. We are talking 10μs vs 100ns, whatever the size of the array here. So, that is really not what cost something. All the (good) proposed solution does more expansive things than that.

Comment: So that is not what cost you. What cost you, (probably ; you haven't shown any code, so I am surmising here) is that you do that incrementally. Adding rows to a a new array one my one. I mean, if I use what is common to most answer (fancy indexing with `[0,2,4]`) what they do is not avoiding the rot/flip. What they do which make them faster than your method, is taking the `[0,2,4]` elements in one single operation, instead of adding columns `[:,0]`, then `[:,2]`, then `[:,4]`. You could use your `rot/flip` method with that idea too, and it would be as fast as their solutions

Comment: So `np.rot90(np.fliplr(M))[0,2,4]`. That is very fast too. It cost 10μs more than `M.T[0,2,4]` or the proposed `M[:,[0,2,4]]`. But that's all. 10μs. Once for all, whatever the size of M (and that is really nothing before the cost of copying the extracted content of `M` in the resulting array).

Comment: So point is: 1. `np.rot90(np.fliplr())` is not what cost you any time here. Even tho it is a strange way to say `M.T`  that is even faster.

Comment: 2. What cost you time is incrematal construction of a resulting array. In that very case, the best way is fancy indexing (as already said in answers, reason why I don't add one: you main answer is that: "fancy indexing"). But generally speaking if you have to build a new array using an incremental addition of new elements, don't use numpy array for that. Never ever create arrays in a loop if you need a loop. So, no `np.array`, no `np.append`, no `np.*stack` in a loop. In such cases, accumulate in a good old python list, and turn it into a numpy array at the last moment.

Comment: `L=[]` `for ix in [0,2,4]: L.append(M.T[i])` then `res=np.array(L)`.

Comment: Not the solution to your problem (again, the solution is the one given 3 times in answers). But that is what you should have done in case where you can't find anything better. Never any `numpy array` building inside the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this *particular* case you can use slicing:

```
after = before[:,::2]
```

Note, this creates a new `np.ndarray` object that is a view over the original buffer.

A more general approach might be something like:

```
after = np.delete(before, [1, 3], axis=1)
```

This shouldn't be a view over the original buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the column you want to keep:

```
after = before[:, [0, 2, 4]]
```

```
[[1 5 1]
 [1 5 3]
 [1 5 0]
 [1 2 9]
 [8 4 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

For large datasets you can use this approach:

```
import numpy as np

# Your initial array
before = np.array([[1, 4, 5, 6, 1], [1, 4, 5, 1, 3], [1, 4, 5, 1, 0], [1, 6, 2, 6, 9], [8, 4, 4, 6, 7]])

# Indices of the elements you want to keep
indices_to_keep = [0, 2, 4]

# Use numpy's advanced indexing to select the desired elements
after = before[:, indices_to_keep]

print(after)
```

This method uses NumPy's advanced indexing capabilities rather than flipping the array multiple times making it much more efficient, especially for large arrays.